# One query join with multiple rows from one table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Ok, so I have two tables in MySQL.  One table holds customer information, the other holds phone numbers.  I need to join these tables in one query to select up to two phone numbers from the phones table as well as customer information.  right now my query is:

```
SELECT customers.name, phones.phone, phones2.phone 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.customerid=customers.id 
LEFT JOIN phones AS phones2 ON phones2.customerid=customers.id 
GROUP BY customers.id;
```

However, this returns the same phone number for phone 1 and phone 2.  essentially what I need to do is offset phones2 by 1, but I don't know how to do that syntactically.

The phones are in a separate table because it's a one to many relationship.

I need this to be in one query because I'm exporting this directly to a csv.

Help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid getting the same phone number twice you could change this:

```
LEFT JOIN phones AS phones2 ON phones2.customerid=customers.id
```

To this:

```
LEFT JOIN phones AS phones2 ON phones2.customerid=customers.id
AND phones2.phone <> phones.phone
```

Comment: this is perfect.  i voted you up and then tried to accept the answer but it said i had to wait 9 minutes.  i'll do it asap.  thank, mark.

Comment: @thejew - You shouldn't need to Join onto the phones table twice for this.

Comment: how would i do it without joining twice?

Comment: @thejew: See the answer he posted.

Comment: @thejew - Well it depends what the criteria are for selecting the 2 phone numbers to bring back. If you just want any 2 numbers then you can use `Max` and `Min`. If there are more involved criteria then it would likely be possible through simulating `row_number`. As far as I understand your current query it is undeterministic as to the 2 you will get.

Answer (score 3):

You just want an arbitrary 0,1, or 2 phone numbers per customer then? If so `Max` and `Min` OK? This will save you a join.

```
SELECT customers.name, 
       MAX(phones.phone) AS phone, 
       CASE WHEN MAX(phones.phone) = MIN(phones.phone) THEN NULL ELSE MIN(phones.phone) END AS phone2
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.customerid=customers.id 
GROUP BY customers.id;
```

Comment: i see.  this would also work fine.  the issue is that i had made my question simpler than my initial problem  was.  i am actually pulling up to three emails and three phone numbers for every customer.  i could work out some solution that would use this, but i think it'd get pretty messy soon.  however, this would definitely work for just two.

Comment: @thejew - So your actual query is going to join onto `phones` 3 times then? I guess you could combine the 2 approaches so you get the `Max` and `Min` from the second JOIN (i.e. from `phones2`) If I had more time I'd try and knock up a `row_number` type solution [(possible in MySQL using variables)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1440#104)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to do remove the cases where the numbers are the same.

```
SELECT customers.name, phones.phone, phones2.phone 
FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN phones ON phones.customerid=customers.id 
LEFT JOIN phones AS phones2 ON phones2.customerid=customers.id 
WHERE phones2.phone != phones.phone
GROUP BY customers.id
```